# Making a pages content go full width in Drupal.

Tags: html, css, iframe, drupal, drupal-7

I've just removed some blocks from a basic page which has an iFrame embedded.

How do I get the iFrame to spread the full width of the page instead of just starting where the blocks ended?

I already have another page which is running at full width, so I believe editing the stylesheet is unnecessary.

The problematic page is [found here](https://www.workbooks.com/portal-test)

The full width page link is: [found here](http://www.workbooks.com/fairusagepolicy)

I need to get the problematic page to go full width. Someone else created the full width page, so I'm unsure how this was created.

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#left {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 212px;
}
#right {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This seemed to work.